# Mac App Rejected for having a blank window

Tags: macos, cocos2d-iphone, appstore-approval

My latest Mac App has been rejected with the following reason:
"When the user launches the app, the main application window appears blank. See screenshot attached."

Here's the screenshot (basically a blank, white mac window):
http://freecloud.com/dl/TPBlank.png

The app (which uses Cocos2D) runs fine for me on my development machine. I even exported the exact binary I submitted to Apple as a Mac Installer Package and installed it on a separate iMac and it runs perfectly.

I'm really at a loss here. Since I can't recreate the problem, I'm not sure how to fix it..

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing my Mac App to display as a blank window for the Apple reviewers but not for me?

Comment: post your appdelegate.m code and perhaps your first scene's init code

Comment: I uploaded my App Delegate here: http://freecloud.com/dl/TPAddDelegate.html

Comment: I uploaded the init and FirstTime function of my main scene here:
http://freecloud.com/dl/TPMainScene.html

Comment: You make a lot of assumptions about window & status bar sizes which may not be true for every system. For example what if the target system is a Retina Macbook, will it still work? What if the statusbar is more or less than 22 points (not sure if this value is never changing)? What if for some reason the user's display resolution was set to something below 1024x768?

Comment: I'm thinking you should figure out why this is the case: "The reason we do this is because the nodeToWorldTransform function doesn't perform correctly unless the initial window size is 1024x768". Then fix it and use the appropriate NSWindow/NSView messages to setup the window size and position. For example you already call window center yet you still change the window frame afterwards. This tells me you haven't really thought through what is going on with the window's size & position during the launch of the app, which in turn lets you make assumptions which may be false on other systems.

Comment: I've tested the app on a MacBook Pro Retina and it works.  I definitely agree that the code is not perfect.  I've tested the archived version (exported as a Mac Installer Package) on another Mac.  I've even set the resolution as low as 800x600, but I still can't recreate the blank window issue...

Comment: Update: 1) I simplified my AppDelegate (see here: http://freecloud.com/dl/TPAppDelegate2.html), but it still was rejected.  2) I tested on another machine with an archive build and it works fine.  3) I don't perform any exception handling that I know of.  4) The Apple reviewer said that they could hear the background music of the main menu playing, so I know that my code is running.  5) The screen is sill blank...

Comment: I compared my new app with my 3 working Mac Apps. I noticed that my existing mac apps include a few frameworks that my new app doesn't:
libz.dylib
Cocoa.framework
ApplicationServices.frameworki
SystemConfiguration.framework

Is it possible that my mac app could run correctly for me without including a needed framework, but then not work for the Apple reviewer?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this a couple times before, usually when the Mac project wasn't correctly setup. Since it works in general but apparently not on every system, I would focus on the things that could cause the initialization to fail on some condition.

One thing you should verify when you test your app on another machine is to make sure you create an Archive build, not just a regular debug (or release) build.

If you're using ARC check all weak properties and ivars because their behavior can be different with optimization enabled, ie assigning to a weak ivar and then adding this ivar as child or to an array will work in Debug, but the ivar will be nil in release because there's no strong reference holding on to the object.

If you perform any exception handling where you simply catch all exceptions, this would also cause the window to silently become white instead of crashing the app (as it should be).